# Do you get rewards for completing an Elder Scrolls: Blade quest if you die afterwards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

If you complete a dungeon quest, and then hit explore, and there are more enemies, what happens if one of them kills you? is the quest still completed and you still get the rewards, or do you have to revive to get them?